# Открыть одновремено файл из нескольких потоков?

Tags: c++

Для работы с файлами использую fopen для открытия файла. Тут вдруг понадобилось одновременно открыть файл нескольким потокам для чтения.

Как открыть файл в таком режиме используя fopen? Или использовать что-то другое?

Answer (score 3):

Ответ ведь очень прост:

```
fopen("file", "r");
```

Если записи в файл не будет, тогда всё будет работать как надо. Если же появится запись, то придётся добавлять механизм сериализации доступа к файлу, чтобы исключить гонки.